# Is the function $g:\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = 1/x^3$ continuous? Why or why not?

Tags: continuity

> Is the function $g:\mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = 1/x^3$ continuous? Why or why not?

A real valued function $f$  is  continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$ if the $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$

And more formally a function is continuous at x=a if there is a number $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that there is an interval I: $f(a) \pm \epsilon$ such that I maps the interval M: $a \pm \delta$.

My problem is i only know how to do the first proof and it's about continuity to a point!

But of course by inspection the domain of $1/x^3$ $\{x\in \mathbb {R} |\, x \neq 0 \}$. So with parameters excluding x=0 f(x) is continuous for all values specified in the domain.

Comment: Prove that $x \mapsto x^3$ and $x \mapsto 1/x$ are continuous. This is a simpler task.

Comment: "And more formally a function is continuous at $x=a$ if there is a number $\epsilon>0$  and $\delta>0$..." This is not correct. It should be "For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that $f$ maps the interval $a\pm\delta_\epsilon$ into the interval $f(a)\pm\epsilon$"
For the second part, pick a general point $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and then work from there.
If you can show that a function is continuous at every point in its domain, you have shown that it is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm  not clear what your question is!  You apparently are saying that you know how to prove that a function is continuous **at a point** but not how to prove a function "is continuous" on it domain?  Is that it?  The definition of "continuous on a set" is "continuous at every point of that set".

So take some general $x_0$ and prove the function is continuous at that $x_0$.  As long as you do not assume any particular properties for $x_0$- except, of course, that it is not $0$- that will prove it is continuous for all x except $x=0$.

Comment: Hey Michael, It's the one on the title and highlighted. "Is the function g:ℝ∖{0}→ℝ given by g(x)=1/x3 continuous? Why or why not?" the other part is just my notes

Comment: So prove that as x approaches a f(x) equal a? For some point. Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon, c > 0$. Since
$$
|g(x) - g(c)| = \frac{|x-c||x^{2}+xc+c^{2}|}{x^{3}c^{3}} < \frac{|x-c|38}{c^{4}} < \varepsilon
$$
if $|x-c| < c/2$ and $< c^{4}\varepsilon/38$,
taking $\delta := \min \{c/2, c^{4}\varepsilon/38 \}$ suffices.

By symmetry the function $x \mapsto 1/x^{3}$ is continuous on $]-\infty, 0[$.

Comment: How did  you find |g(x)-g(c)|

Comment: By suitably majorizing $|x-c|$. But the sense of suitability requires experience. :)

Comment: Is my comment a reply you were seeking?

Comment: Yes it was @chou but i have a feeling that there might another way to answer the question and that i was not thought this method.